# Why was my network synchronization question closed as offtopic?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-request, close-reasons, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Super User post: [Real-Time Sync Utility](https://superuser.com/questions/1140617/real-time-sync-utility)

My question got recently closed as off-topic. While my actual question (what I wanted to know) was on topic in the first place, I added an ending that suggested I was looking for a software recommendation.

This **was put on hold as off-topic** (which was correct because I did not clearly stated what I was looking for).
**I edited the question** to clarify that it complies to the [OnTopic guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) shortly after.

The question got apparently reviewed again, but was not re-opened.
I did not bother too much about it at first because I was working on a solution by myself.
While I solved the problem, the question was deleted as abandoned.

I would like to answer the question, but am not able to do so.
I believe my question fits on superuser after carefully reading [OnTopic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and some other Help-Center posts.

**Is there any reason why the question was not reopened after my edit?**
I'm not aware of any guidelines I'm violating with this question.

Not sure whether I should include the text of the original question here as only people with 10k+ rep can view it, but it's quite long.

Comment: Ben N pretty much nailed it in his answer.  For me, the original wording of the product discussions also seemed to point to a request for a product recommendation.  You've done a good job of cleaning up the question.  I also tweaked it to address what I originally saw as problems.  The question is still a bit broad ("help me design a solution" questions tend to be), but you're looking to self-answer.  I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout the question, you provide examples of programs you've tried and some specific concerns you have about your situation. That's great! Unfortunately, recommendations for off-site resources (including programs) are off-topic here, as noted by the closure reason.

It is possible to ask questions that will probably require third-party software, but here, it looks like the question was closed because of the title ("Real-Time Sync Utility") and the opening sentence:

> I'm looking for something to synchronize my Computers with a NAS in the local network.

It's easy to forget to update the title after changing the body - I've missed it myself a couple times! - but people usually use the title to assess what the question is primarily about. Modifying the title to describe your situation would help.

You [did adjust](https://superuser.com/posts/1140617/revisions) the closing sentence, and that's good. A bit more wordsmithing in the rest of the question might be able to make it clear that you're not necessarily looking for a software recommendation. In fact, your question does have one reopen vote pending at the moment.

Though if you *are* looking for a software recommendation, we have a sister site for that: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thanks to all the information you included, you have most of an SR.SE question already.

Comment: I agree that I should have been more careful editing the question. But I've looked into SR before editing the question and did not feel it belonged there, as it is for ["software ready-to-use"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is not what I'm looking for. The solution I found for myself now is pretty much scripted, I used unison (and other tools) though. The tricky point was to use it _right_. The reason I'm referring other programs I've tried is that I wanted to say why I don't just use XYZ

Comment: @Qw3ry Ah, that makes sense. Since you're clearly still interested in your question and have not abandoned it, I've cast the last necessary undelete vote.

Comment: BTW thank you for the detailed answer. I edited the question accordingly and hope it will be reopened so I can share my solution.